# What APIs can I use to make a speech recognition program for windows and raspberry pi?

Tags: api, raspberry-pi, cross-platform, speech-recognition

I want to make a program that uses speech recognition to do basic commands. I want to develop it and be able to run it in Windows, but eventually I want to be able to run it on a Raspberry Pi, most likely using Linux or freeBSD (probably Linux.) What APIs are available? I have heard of Google having one but don't know where to find it, and not sure how it works, and Microsoft has one, but I think it is windows specific. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try CMUSphinx, it's successfully used on Linux, in particular on low-resource computers like Raspberry Pi and on Windows.

For more details on using CMUSphinx see the [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial).